# Moya switch between stub and normal request

Tags: ios, swift, moya

I have NetworkManager class( in production target) that have different n/w requests.
Now using Moya if I want to make production request I use below

```
let provider = MoyaProvider<MyService>()
```

For TestTarget request I use below

```
 let provider = MoyaProvider<MyService>(stubClosure: MoyaProvider.immediatelyStub)
```

So if I want to switch between how to create provider for both. what is the best way. 
Checking target in each method ?
OR something other efficient way

Below is my code for request

```
 func getRequest(onCompletion: @escaping NetworkCallBacks.ServiceResponse) {

    //let provider = MoyaProvider<MyService>() //for production
    let provider = MoyaProvider<MyService>(stubClosure: MoyaProvider.immediatelyStub) // for test
    provider.request(.getList(queryParameter: “Apple”)) { result in

        switch result {
        case let .success(moyaResponse):
        case let .failure(error):
            break
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you pass some `test` variable while creating your network manager or while calling request function? I do it this way:

```
extension Api.Service {

    convenience init(test: Bool) {
        self.init()
        self.test = test
    }
}
```

And then while getting a provider you can lazily get test or prod provider

```
func getProvider() -> RxMoyaProvider<Target> {
    return RxMoyaProvider<Target>(stubClosure: stubClosure)
}

func stubClosure(_ target: Target) -> Moya.StubBehavior {
    return test ? Moya.StubBehavior.immediate : Moya.StubBehavior.never
}
```

In your case you can do it this way:

```
func getRequest(onCompletion: @escaping NetworkCallBacks.ServiceResponse, test: Bool = false)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to create `NetworkManager`struct with `stubClosure` dependency so you can pass stubClosure in constructor while creating NetworkManager. Provide default value as `MoyaProvider.neverStub` for stubClosure so you don't have to pass for production environment. Only when you want to test then you can pass `MoyaProvider.immediatelyStub`

```
public struct NetworkingManager<T: TargetType> {
    let provider: MoyaProvider<T>

    init(stubClosure: @escaping MoyaProvider<T>.StubClosure = MoyaProvider.neverStub) {
        self.provider = MoyaProvider<T>(stubClosure: stubClosure)
    }
}
```

When you want to test you can pass stubClosure as below

```
let networkManager = NetworkManager<MyService>(strubClosure: MoyaProvider.immediatelyStub)
```